# Telescoping function Revealed.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I found Summation $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n \ (-1)^n}{(y+1)^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{(x+y+1)}$$

However $x$ is related to $y$. $y \ge |x|$.

Just the same,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{x}\frac{x!y!(-1)^n}{ (x-n)!(y+1+n)!} = \frac{1}{(x+y+1)}$$

For x and y integers >= 0.

Comment: correction y>= abs(x)

Comment: Using the transformation (y+1) =Y and x=X^2, and integrating the telescope, holding Y constant, yields the power series for arctangent X,

Comment: Please edit the question *once* to say what you mean, rather than nearly twenty times.

Comment: Yup. 20+ edits is excessive, because every edit bumps the question to the front page. Contrary to what you may initially think that does not help your cause. The reason is that such antics push other questions off the front page, hence irritates many regulars, and leads to your question getting **negative attention**. Yet, there are those cases where a question needs to be edited a lot to make it look polished. In those cases the advice is to use [the sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4666/11619). Feel free to use it, and copy/paste the question here when you are happy with it.

Comment: @ Jyrki Jyrki Lahtonen; I have no idea of anything about editing. But kindly thank you for the advice.  You are a gentleman. Seems like this web-side as far as communication goes may not be worth it.  All the best. And thank you for your gentle advise.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Write $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^n x^n}{(y+1)^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac {(-x)^n }{(y+1)^{n+1}}=\frac 1{y+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac {-x}{y+1}\right)^n=\frac 1{y+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n$$ where $a=-\frac {x}{y+1}$.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Note that x and y are interchangeable, so let y be x.

Comment: @EstebanRamirezLopez. You are very welcome.